# Covington Gloss in Parbox/Makebox/Minipage

Tags: boxes, linguistics

I am using LyX and I'm trying to place a Convington Gloss ([Covington usage](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/covington/covington.pdf)) inside a `\parbox`, `\makebox`, or `minipage` but I get the error:

http://pastie.org/1814468

Here is the file:

http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/iHOSWyqg

Comment: In general, it looks like I'm having difficulty with the Gloss. For example, I cannot place it in a table. http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/z_uSCKGJ

Comment: In general, `covington` should be avoided for both examples and glosses. Instead use either [`gb4e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) or [`linguex`](http://ctan.org/linguex) (which both use the `cgloss4e` package for glosses.)  Independent of this, what effect are you trying to achieve overall? There may be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use minipage at all. It's sufficient to put it in a `\vtop` and then box that. Note that I subtracted the space added and the width of the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{covington}
\begin{document}
\setbox0\vtop{
\hsize\dimexpr\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule\relax
\gll dat Jan het boek lest
that Jan the book reads
\glt that Jan is reading the book
\glend
}
\noindent\framebox{\box0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This looks like it works, but I cannot in turn put this box inside another Minipage (getting the same error as before). This other minipage contains a syntax tree. I could probably put the entire thing in a \vtop like you show, but I was trying to use Miniboxes in order to use LyX instant preview feature.

Comment: @Gus: I can't help you with LyX and I've found over the years that `minipage` is _almost_ never needed. (Okay, clearly it is never needed, but it is almost never useful.)

Comment: @Gus: In this case, my guess is it's related to the fact that `\fbox` and thus `\framebox` tokenizes its argument [needlessly](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2011/01/better-mbox-and-fbox.html), but I didn't actually check how `covington` works.

Comment: That's an interesting link and I hope to understand more deeply about LaTeX. Is the \vtop\hsize... \framebox{\box0} code a common idiom? I'm trying to make the box be 50% of the textwidth by replacing \columnwidth with \0.5\textwidth but that's not the proper syntax.

Comment: @Gus: Replace `\columnwidth` with `.5\textwidth` and it should work just fine.

Comment: I get the error: http://pastie.org/1814680
(I'm not sure how to format comments, but I'll include the error below too)
\hsize\dimexpr\.5
                       \textwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule\relax
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Comment: @Gus: You're adding in a backslash before the `.5` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @TH: sorry about that! I was having difficulty parsing that...